# Como usar um construtor com duas ou mais classes?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, c++11

Estou em desenvolvimento de uma biblioteca de orientação-a-objetos. Criei um iterator para meu futuro container. Tenho `advance_iterator` e `regress_iterator`. Ambos dão origem a `bidirectional_iterator`. O código é:

```
#ifndef OBJSTD_ADVANCE_ITERATOR
#define OBJSTD_ADVANCE_ITERATOR
#include <cstddef>
namespace objstd
{
    template <typename data_type> class advance_iterator
    {
        public:
        advance_iterator(data_type* data_ref)
        {
            this->data_reference = data_ref;
        }
        advance_iterator(const advance_iterator& it) = default;
        advance_iterator(advance_iterator&& it) = default;
        virtual bool operator > (const advance_iterator& it) const
        {
            return this->data_reference > it.data_reference;
        }
        virtual bool operator < (const advance_iterator& it) const
        {
            return this->data_reference < it.data_reference;
        }
        bool operator == (const advance_iterator& it) const
        {
            return this->data_reference == it.data_reference;
        }
        bool operator != (const advance_iterator& it) const
        {
            return this->data_reference != it.data_reference;
        }
        virtual bool operator >= (const advance_iterator& it) const
        {
            return (*this).operator>(it) || (*this).operator==(it);
        }
        virtual bool operator <= (const     advance_iterator& it)const
        {
            return (*this).operator<(it) || (*this).operator==(it);
        }
        virtual advance_iterator& operator+=(const size_t skips)
        {
            this->data_reference += skips;
            return *this;
        }
        virtual advance_iterator& operator++()
        {
            *this += 1;
            return *this;
        }
        virtual advance_iterator& operator++(int)
        {
            advance_iterator& state = *this;
            this->operator++();
            return state;
        }
        virtual advance_iterator operator+ (const size_t skips)
        {
            return this->data_reference + skips;
        }
        //must be declared virtual for non-conservational
        virtual data_type& operator*() const
        {
            return *this->data_reference;
        }
        protected:
        data_type* data_reference;
    };
}

#endif // OBJSTD_ADVANCE_ITERATOR
```

`regress_iterator`

```
#ifndef OBJSTD_REGRESS_ITERATOR
#define OBJSTD_REGRESS_ITERATOR
#include <cstddef>
namespace objstd
{
    template <typename data_type> class regress_iterator
    {
        public:
        regress_iterator(data_type* data_ref)
        {
            this->data_reference = data_ref;
        }
        regress_iterator(const regress_iterator& it) = default;
        regress_iterator(regress_iterator&& it) = default;
        virtual bool operator > (const regress_iterator& it) const
        {
            return this->data_reference > it.data_reference;
        }
        virtual bool operator < (regress_iterator& it) const
        {
            return this->data_reference < it.data_reference;
        }
        bool operator == (regress_iterator& it) const
        {
            return this->data_reference == it.data_reference;
        }
        bool operator != (regress_iterator& it) const
        {
            return this->data_reference != it.data_reference;
        }
        virtual bool operator >= (regress_iterator& it) const
        {
            return (*this).operator>(it) || (*this).operator==(it);
        }
        virtual bool operator <= (regress_iterator& it)const
        {
            return (*this).operator<(it) || (*this).operator==(it);
        }
        virtual regress_iterator& operator-=(size_t backwards)
        {
            this->data_reference -= backwards;
            return *this;
        }
        virtual regress_iterator& operator--()
        {
            *this -= 1;
            return *this;
        }
        virtual regress_iterator& operator--(int)
        {
            regress_iterator& state = *this;
            this->operator--();
            return state;
        }
        virtual regress_iterator operator- (size_t backwards)
        {
            return this->data_reference - backwards;
        }
        //must be declared virtual for non-conservational
        virtual data_type& operator*() const
        {
            return *this->data_reference;
        }
        protected:
        data_type* data_reference;
    };
}

#endif // OBJSTD_REGRESS_ITERATOR
```

E `bidirectional_iterator` é definido assim:

```
#ifndef OBJSTD_BIDIRECTIONAL_ITERATOR
#define OBJSTD_BIDIRECTIONAL_ITERATOR
#include "regress_iterator.hpp"
#include "advance_iterator.hpp"
namespace objstd
{
    template <typename data_type> class bidirectional_iterator : public advance_iterator <data_type>, public regress_iterator <data_type>
    {
    };
}

#endif // OBJSTD_BIDIRECTIONAL_ITERATOR
```

O problema é ao criar uma instancia do tipo `bidirectional_iterator(ponteiro)`, pois o compilador não sabe como inicializar. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em C++ os construtores não são herdados implicitamente pela classe derivada justamente para evitar esse tipo de ambiguidade. No C++11 você pode explicitamente herdar um dos construtores usando `using`, que não faria muito sentido no seu caso, já que existem duas bases.

A solução para você é implementar um construtor na sua classe:

```
template <typename data_type>
class bidirectional_iterator : public advance_iterator<data_type>,
                               public regress_iterator<data_type>
{
public:

    bidirectional_iterator(data_type* data_ref) :
      advance_iterator<data_type>(data_ref),
      regress_iterator<data_type>(data_ref) {
        // do nothing
    }

};
```

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer isso, mas recebi o erro de que não há tais membros na classe.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Opa, faltou o argumento template ali na inicialização. Corrigido.

Comment: Agora entendi; obrigado. Vou checar depois que dormir ^cansado^.

Comment: Guilherme, alguns erros me apareceram por ambiguidade e não sei o que fazer. Você pode me ajudar?

Comment: @LucasHenrique, será que você não está com algum problema de compilador? Eu testei [o código do Guilherme aqui](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b934db8c66d91d4c) e não tive nenhum erro...

Comment: @Massa ele atualizou antes do teu comentário.

Comment: Então acho que você pode marcar a resposta dele como sendo a correta! :D